# Add to QByteArray with 1 byte the 9-th bit

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I have a situation right now when I have after reading the byte stream from COM port in object of `QByteArray` type exactly and only 1 byte of data. BUT one very non-friendly protocol requires to have 9 bits of data after reading data from COM port.

But according to win32API function: `ReadFile(....)` I can read from the COM stream ONLY bytes= 1,2,3.....

So - That's why I am reading only 8 bits=1 byte with help of this function and with help of some operations with parity bit I am calculating the value of the 9th bit of generalized data...

So on one hand I have 1 byte (8 bits) of proper(real) data - on another hand I have a value of this 9th bit (0 or 1); 2 objects which in sum must create the value of generalized data.
How I can combine these objects into one & final `QByteArray` object? Because the global function `ReadComData` can and must return only `QByteArray` object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. If you have only 9 bits of data in the COM port, it seems that you cannot read them at all. But if you have many 9-bit items in the port, you can read them into QByteArray. It will contain all data but it will be difficult to access each 9-bit item since items are shared between two bytes and misaligned. Is this your problem?

Comment: he-he)) I CAN read  9bits of data - 8 bits as usual - through the function ReadFile(). And the 9th bit I can get from the bit of parity.
So - do not find the black cat in black box especially when there is no cat at all)).
The question is about the ability to combine the QByteArray object which contains 8 bits=1 byte with standalone bit of data - 0 or 1.
So - how to do this?
How to write operation QByteArray = QByteArray+BitOfData.

Answer (score 1):

UARTs cannot "write" 9-bit data.  On the wire, your (typically 8-bit) data are usually framed between a start-bit and a stop-bit, so you have 10 bits transmitted for every byte you send.  If you have a parity bit, it is transmitted after the last data bit, but before the stop bit.  But this is generated by the sending UART, not part of a protocol.  A data bus for a typical UART 16550 is only 8-bits wide (you can actually send 5-, 6-, 7-, or 8-bit data).

On the receiving end, the UART has to be configured based on what is on the wire.  If your sender is using a parity bit, then you program the UART (via the "COM" port settings) accordingly.  The parity bit is just to help check for errors on the wire.  It is based on the data bits -- you cannot put another data bit in a parity bit.  The receiving UART can be used to check for parity errors (read via the line status register (LSR)), and this can be passed up to you via system calls.

It is possible your protocol is splitting up the data across multiple bytes.  If that's the case, then convert two bytes into one 16-bit word and mask the 6 bits you don't want to use.

Comment: No - mdb protocol (vending machines) IS using real 9 bits and I can use parity bit for virtualizing of "not-a-real" 9 bit of sent data frame. Google can show to you these techniques.....
So the problem is ONLY in combining of 8 bits of real data with the value of 9th mode bit into one single QByteArray object...

Comment: @graphElem:  I don't understand why you want to use a QByteArray (a container of 8-bit data) to work on 9-bit data.  Use 16-bit words and a little bit-bashing to get what you want.

Comment: because the global function 'ReadComData' which is indeed returning the result of reading of COM port stream WAS created far-far before my current task. And so ALL points of entrance of this function in a huge amount of our code are expecting to get qbytearray object as result of reading data from COM port.
And only now we figured out that not only 8 bits are expected to be found at COM stream.
That's why now we are looking for the ideas how to combine 8bits of data with 9th bit of mode... and put it into qbytearray......